# Is there a significance to the number 63385 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, benchmarking

I am iterating over large arrays and sets while attempting to benchmark Arrays vs Sets performance.

I eventually figured out that Sets seem to be faster if the length of the collection is exactly 63385 or above.

Arrays seem to be faster at any length below that.

Here is what I see:

**Length 63385 and above**

```
map#Array->big x 119 ops/sec ±1.62% (76 runs sampled)
map#Set->big x 349 ops/sec ±4.11% (81 runs sampled)
```

**Length 63384 and below**

```
map#Array->medium x 2,407 ops/sec ±0.48% (94 runs sampled)
map#Set->medium x 818 ops/sec ±0.83% (90 runs sampled)
```

Here is my benchmark code (I know it may be the source of the weirdness I see).

```
const Benchmark = require('benchmark');

const suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

const array = [];
let mappedArray = [];

const set = new Set();
const mappedSet = new Set();

const mediumArray = [];
let mediumMappedArray = [];
const mediumSet = new Set();
const mediumMappedSet = new Set();

const max = 63385;

for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  array.push(i);
  set.add(i);

  if (i < 63385) {
    smallArray.push(i);
    smallSet.add(i);
  }
}

suite.add('map#Array->big', () => {
  mappedArray = array.map((val, index) => val * 2);
});

suite.add('map#Set->big', () => {
  set.forEach((val) => mappedSet.add(val * 2));
});

suite.add('map#Array->medium', () => {
  mediumMappedArray = mediumArray.map((val, index) => val * 2);
});

suite.add('map#Set->medium', () => {
  mediumSet.forEach((val) => mediumMappedSet.add(val * 2));
});

suite.run();
```

What causes the sudden change?

Comment: What hardware are you using?  This looks like you've found the cutoff between L2 cache (256kiB on many x86 CPUs) and L3 cache (3 to 8 MiB).  Use `perf stat` to look for LLC-loads being much higher with the larger array, because loads no longer hit in L2 cache.  Or use `ocperf.py` to look at counters for L2 hit/miss events.  `63384` times 4 bytes per `int` (if JIT manages to optimize) is pretty close to 256kiB.  Assume that some extra L2 space is taken up by other things, or HW prefetch overshoot causes evictions if your array exactly fills L2 cache.